# Why do I get asked to set a new Administrator password when demoting a Domain Controller?

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012, hyper-v

For testing purposes we set up a Hyper-V virtual machine as a Domain Controller.

We now have a dedicated physical server as Primary Domain Controller so I want to demote the virtual machine but I want it to continue being a domain server as we use it for other things (file sharing etc.).

DNS is configured and running on the new physical Domain Controller and is Primary Domain Controller.

Is there anything else to check before demoting the old Domain Controller on the virtual machine?

Why do I get asked to set a new Administrator password when I go to demote it?

Answer (score 1):

Demoting Active Directory domain controller on Windows Server 2008/2012 you have to set a password for local administrator account which was unavailable on a server as it was Domain Controller where local accounts do not exist

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh472163.aspx

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc771844%28v=ws.10%29.aspx